# StatusCode = 407, ReasonPhrase: 'authenticationrequired apenas em desenvolvimento

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, proxy

Tenho uma aplicação em ASP.NET que acessa um servidor remoto (fora do domínio da empresa; URL externa) para verificar alguns dados.
Quando eu rodo a aplicação em ambiente de desenvolvimento - localhost acessando URL externa,  eu tomo erro 407. Esse mesmo código quando publicado para o servidor de homologação, isso não acontece.
Meu problema está sendo encontrar uma forma de identificar as credenciais do usuário no localhost. Estou usando o seguinte código para verificar o proxy:

```
var oHand = new HttpClientHandler();    
if (WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(new Uri(pURL)) != null)
       {
                    oHand.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
                    oHand.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                }
```

A única forma que eu consegui fazer funcionar foi colocando dados do usuário (login de rede e senha) no web.config, o que complica o controle de versão, pois pode colocar a senha de rede de alguém da equipe exposta por acidente.
Alguém teria uma sugestão?

Answer (score 0):

Anderson Oliveira, veja isso, talvez te ajude:

Esse método pode evitar a necessidade de HARD CODE (código chumbado) ou configurar credenciais de proxy, que pode ser desejável.

Coloque isso em seu arquivo de configuração do aplicativo, provavelmente no "app.config". Visual Studio irá renomeá-lo para "NomeDoSeuAplicativo.exe.config" na compilação, e ele terminará ao lado de seu executável. Se você não tiver um arquivo de configuração do aplicativo, basta adicionar um usando Adicionar novo item no Visual Studio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Leia mais em:

[Proxy Basic Authentication in C#: HTTP 407 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603093/proxy-basic-authentication-in-c-http-407-error)

[407 Proxy Authentication Required](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/407)

[(407) Proxy Authentication Required.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c06d3032-dceb-4a1a-bb6a-778fd13a938a/407-proxy-authentication-required?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: @fabioln , obrigado pela sua contribuição. Contudo, eu já tentei isso também. Em desenvolvimento, com essa config, não encontra as credenciais do usuário, imagino eu por não rodar diretamente na máquina e sim no IIS. Em uma app Windows que eu tenho, funciona normalmente. Mas em Desenv não rola...